# Java 8 functional: How to compute a list of dependent evolutions of an object?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I want to write the following code in a functional way with streams and lambdas:

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>();
things.add(thing);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    thing = computeNextValue(thing);
    things.add(thing);
}
```

Something in the way of this...

```
Supplier<Thing> initial = Thing::new;
List<Things> things = IntStream.range(0, 100).???(...).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<Thing> things = Stream.iterate(new Thing(), t->computeNextValue(t))
                           .limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also use a method reference for `t->computeNextValue(t)`.

If `computeNextValue` is a `static` method replace `t->computeNextValue(t)` with `ContainingClass::computeNextValue`, otherwise use `this::computeNextValue`.